# Is it realistic for a terrorist to leave his phone number behind in the call list?

Tags: plot-explanation, source-code

In [Source Code](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0945513/), it is shown that by redialing a number from the same phone that was connected to the bomb, Capt. found the guy finally who set up the bomb.

But is it realistic for a terrorist to leave any loose (major actually) end like this in such planning?

This gives birth to two questions. What was the necessity for the terrorist to call the number? And if it was called for checking the connection purpose, should not the terrorist have deleted it?

I think it is a major plot-hole in the movie and catching of the terrorist should have been done in another way.

Comment: Why should he care about the mobile phone that will explode anyway? AFAIU he couldn't know that someone will send agent to the past to check the bomb.

Comment: That is the loose end thinking I am talking about. No expert in crime would do a perfect work with this type of silly mistake. I guess deleting a number from the call list is not that hard. So why let it stay in the list?

Comment: Maybe it's some kind of several-step activation. Anyone, terrorist actually succeeded in first n realities presented in the movie. So it was reasonable to not expect somebody to find a phone before an explosion.

Comment: Do not confuse it with parallel realities. The terrorist is not aware of the realities. Tell me why did he not delete in the current reality where rutledge and goodwin lives? He should have deleted it in the first place _practically_!

Comment: _"Is it realistic for a terrorist...?"_ and _"Why didn't the terrorist in the movie...?"_ are __different__ questions.

Comment: @Oliver_C, _It is not realistic for a terrorist_ practically that is why if somebody argues it is practical I should ask him so tell me _Why didn't the terrorist in the movie delete the no_ where it was an easy way out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like default locale says, the phone would explode along with the bomb; So nobody would ever get to see it/recall the last number. Removing the last number should only be done if the bomber fears to be discovered. As the bomber has successfully bombed before and nobody on the train (without time travel capacities) can even begin to expect something, he doesn't expect someone to find his bomb.

You have to place yourself in the bomber's place. If you assume the bomb to fail, then you could just as well abort the mission. There's also a million other more important things to worry about (getting the components, building the bomb, smuggling it on the train, installing it, other bombings,...). Why not use a better/more reliable stand alone system (other than GSM) to trigger the bomb. Nobody would be able to trace that. Why not use a more basic phone with no memory at all? Why did he call the phone in the first place?

Just one of the many design choices you have to make while building a bomb and it doesn't seem too important compared to major issues (I would worry about hiding my explosives).

**EDIT :** Just thought of  another explanation.
If you want the bomb to explode only when receiving a call from a specific number, then you have to store that number in the cell phone. If you don't, it might blow when a telemarketer calls for an advanced subscription plan.

Comment: That is my point. If he has done so many things successfully, why leaving the call list undeleted? Anyway, let us see what community thinks on it...

Comment: @Mistu4u Just thought of another explanation

Comment: This one sounds more logical.

Comment: yeah, wonder why I didn't see it sooner :p Then again, it's also a design choice (so my entire explanation isn't useless): Do you go for the cell phone with tracking or do you go for special detonators, which leads you to the grand set of other, more important decisions...

Comment: Really a very good explanation. +1 to you.

Comment: hahaha, awesome EDIT @Mistu4u, laughed lots!